# Python C API escape string

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, embed, python-c-api

I want to use python C API to escape a string. The string would be later used in a python eval as an argument for a python method, so currently I'm using this construct:

```
char* Escape(char* string) {
    PyObject *var = PyUnicode_FromString(string);
    free(string);
    PyObject *varRepr = PyObject_Repr(var);
    char* str = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(varRepr);

    Py_DECREF(var);
    Py_DECREF(varRepr);

    return str;

}
```

Is there a more effective/better way?

Comment: The better way would be not using `eval`.

Comment: I believe it is also sufficient to escape all characters <32 and the quotes you're using with `\octal` or `\xhex`